# element > element in SASS?

Tags: css, sass

i've searched around and just not found the answer to this, but hoping it's a simple answer to be honest!

I'm learning SASS, and have been attempting to convert an existing .css file.
I came across a selector in there like this.

```
div > p { 
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

how is this achieved with SASS?

is it the same? or is there a way to nest it like you do with multiple classes like this...

```
.header{
    .p{
        color:black;
    }
}
```

please point me in the right direction!

Comment: Did you try *anything*?  Anything at all?

Comment: yes, i did try a few things. I didn't include them because i didn't think showing my failed attempts would have added any value to the actual question. and i'm sorry i did not come across the previously answered question, i did look, but must've worded the search differently and it didn't turn up an answer for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you go:

```
div {
  > p {
       // You style
      }
}
```

**Explanation:**

When you use nesting like this:

```
div {
    p {
       //
      }
}
```

It compiles into:

```
div p {
       //
}
```

So if you want to be a direct child

```
div > p {
       //
}
```

Then you need to specify it.

Comment: Please explain your solution a little

Comment: thank you @technotronic, I appreciate your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

something like the following should work:

```
.header{
    &>.p{
        color:black;
    }
}
```

Comment: no need to use `&` on this case